# SQL Server Transpose / Unpivot All columns of the Table

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to perform a Transpose for all the column table using `UNPIVOT` in SQL Server but with no results

Here is my table

| ManufacturerID | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Manufacturer | ABC | KW | MC | TZ |
| Logo | URL1 | URL2 | URL3 | URL4 |

The output desired

| ManufacturerID | Manufacturer | Logo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | URL1 |
| 2 | kw | URL2 |
| 3 | MC | URL3 |
| 4 | TZ | URL4 |

How could I achieve this result using `UNPIVOT`?

My attempt:

```sql
SELECT [ManufacturerID], [Manufacturer], [Logo] FROM ( SELECT [Column1] , [Column2],[Column3],[Column4],[Column5] FROM [TestFormation].[dbo].[IN_Manufacturer] ) unpivot ([ManufacturerID] FOR Name_ToDrop1 IN ([Column2],[Column3],[Column4],[Column5] )) AS p1 unpivot ([Manufacturer] FOR Name_ToDrop2 IN ([Column2],[Column3],[Column4],[Column5] )) AS p2 unpivot (Logo] FOR Name_ToDrop3 IN ([Column2],[Column3],[Column4],[Column5] )) AS p
```

Comment: FYI, rather than [deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73106646/how-to-transpose-all-the-table-using-the-first-column-as-the-column-names-in-s) your question, there is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73106646/edit) feature

Comment: If you're in PowerBI (I assume that's what you mean by "BI"), then I would likely suggest that you should be (un)pivoting in PowerBI, not the SQL layer. Though if you normalise your design, that would be an even better solution; then you don't need to unpivot.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You say you've attempted using `UNPIVOT` too; what was that attempt? Why didn't it work? If you got no results (no rows?) then that likely isn't the `UNPIVOT` but your `WHERE` or `JOIN`s filtering out the data.

Comment: Sounds like you need both a pivot and an unpivot

Comment: It would be helpful if one of you guys could show a specific code to manage to do that,

Comment: I think i have to make a mix between Pivot and Unpivot using also some self join if i'm not wrong, but i don't know where to start to make it

Comment: Again, there is an [edit] feature, @Rahim ...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to both unpivot and pivot your data here. *Hopefully* the reason you want to do this is to *fix* your design; if it isn't make it so that it is. You design is poor, and denormalised (what happens when you need a 5th or 6th column for example?).

I don't use the `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` operators here, however, but use a `VALUES` table construct and conditional aggregation; both are far more versatile than the restrictive operators.

This gives the following solution:

```sql
SELECT UP.Col AS ManufacturerID,
       MAX(CASE V.ManufacturerID WHEN 'Manufacturer' THEN UP.VaL END) AS Manufacturer,
       MAX(CASE V.ManufacturerID WHEN 'Logo' THEN UP.VaL END) AS Logo
FROM (VALUES('Manufacturer','ABC','KW','MC','TZ'),
            ('Logo','URL1','URL2','URL3','URL4'))V(ManufacturerID,[1],[2],[3],[4])
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1,[1]),(2,[2]),(3,[3]),(4,[4]))UP(Col,Val)
GROUP BY UP.Col;
```

---

Based on the comments it seems you "have" to use `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT`; I'm not sure why and I suggest against it, but if you "must" then it would look like this:

```sql
SELECT P.Col AS ManufacturerID,
       P.Manufacturer,
       P.Logo
FROM (SELECT ManufacturerID,
             [1],
             [2],
             [3],
             [4]
      FROM (VALUES('Manufacturer','ABC','KW','MC','TZ'),
                  ('Logo','URL1','URL2','URL3','URL4'))V(ManufacturerID,[1],[2],[3],[4]))YT
UNPIVOT (
    Val FOR Col IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) UP
PIVOT (MAX(Val)
       FOR ManufacturerID IN (Manufacturer,Logo)) P;
```

Personally, I think this is pretty confusing to look at.

Obviously the sample data in both solutions would be replaced by your table, the above just use a `VALUES` table construct in the absence of DDL and DML in the question.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f4472690aea7f31f9664d4468564cd6e)